# UIView disappears after close and reopen the app [custom UIView category]

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, drawrect

I created a category of UIView to draw easily without having to make a subclass of a UIView. 
The problem is that when I close the app and I re-open (normally in low memory conditions) the UIView drawing disappears.

I show you the code of the category:

**UIView+DrawBlock.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

// Blocks
typedef void(^DrawBlock)(CGContextRef context, CGRect drawFrame);
typedef void(^CompletionBlock)(UIView *view);

@interface UIView (DrawBlock)

- (void)drawInside:(DrawBlock)block withResult:(CompletionBlock)completion;

@end
```

**UIView+DrawBlock.m**

```
#import "UIView+DrawBlock.h"

#pragma mark - Auxiliar UIView
@interface DrawingView : UIView
@property (strong, nonatomic) DrawBlock drawBlock;
- (void)setDrawRectBlock:(DrawBlock)block;
@end

@implementation DrawingView
- (void)setDrawRectBlock:(DrawBlock)block {
    _drawBlock = block;
    if (_drawBlock) {
        [self setNeedsDisplay];
    }
}
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    if (_drawBlock) {
        _drawBlock(context, rect);
        _drawBlock = nil;
    }

}
@end

#pragma mark - Category
@implementation UIView (DrawBlock)
- (void)drawInside:(DrawBlock)block withResult:(CompletionBlock)completion {
    if (block) {
        DrawingView *drawView = [[DrawingView alloc] init];
        drawView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
        drawView.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
        drawView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        [self addSubview:drawView];

        NSDictionary *views = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(drawView);
        NSArray *constraints = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[drawView]|"
                                                                       options:0
                                                                       metrics:nil
                                                                         views:views];
        [self addConstraints:constraints];
        constraints = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[drawView]|"
                                                              options:0
                                                              metrics:nil
                                                                views:views];
        [self addConstraints:constraints];
        [drawView setDrawRectBlock:block];

        if (completion != nil) {
            completion(drawView);
        }
    }
}

@end
```

I think the problem is in this part of the code:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    if (_drawBlock) {
        _drawBlock(context, rect);
        _drawBlock = nil;
    }

}
```

If I comment this line:

```
_drawBlock = nil;
```

it seems that everything works, but memory consumption increase without stopping and the app becomes very slow.

Any idea? Subclass is not an option.

Thanks!

**Update 1** Example of usage

```
- (void)drawOnView {

    [self.view drawInside:^(CGContextRef context, CGRect drawFrame) {

        // Oblique lines
        CGMutablePathRef obliquePath = CGPathCreateMutable();
        CGFloat height = CGRectGetHeight(drawFrame);
        for (CGFloat x = -height; x < CGRectGetWidth(drawFrame); x += 7.5) {
            CGPathMoveToPoint(obliquePath, nil, x, 0.0);
            CGPathAddLineToPoint(obliquePath, nil, x + height, height);
        }
        CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.0 alpha:0.04].CGColor);
        CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 2.0);
        CGContextAddPath(context, obliquePath);
        CGContextStrokePath(context);
        CGPathRelease(obliquePath);


    } withResult:^(UIView *view) {

        [self.view sendSubviewToBack:view];

    }];

}
```

[image]

Comment: In this case, what is exactly is DrawBlock?

Comment: is _drawBlock necessary? I don't see it being called anywhere. It's only calling setNeedsDisplay if _drawBlock is being set.

Comment: Where do you call `drawOnView` from?

Comment: drawInside is a block, not called directly

Comment: Ups! sorry, "drawOnView" is called from viewDidLoad or viewWillAppear. I tried multiple ways but nothing

Answer (score 0):

First, blocks should be copied, not retained. Replace `strong` by `copy` in the `drawBlock` property declaration.

Next, you are right, you should not nil the block as `DrawingView` `drawRect:` will need it to redisplay.

The memory problem probably is a retain cycle. Make sure you *don't acess self nor its ivars* from inside the block. Weakify self outside the block as

```
__weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self;


[self drawInside:^{
    // use only weakSelf 
} ...
```

---

If this doesn't help show a `drawInside:` call example with your blocks. Also, from where do you call it?

---

Finally, given that `DrawingView` takes its full superview size, it might more efficient having a single `DrawingView` which stores the draw blocks in an internal array, and drawing all of them from a single `drawRect` call. Creating a new `DrawingView` for each block, with the constraints at all, seems a bit overhead.

But this is more advanced, I suggest you get the basic case working first.

Comment: I tried __weak but doesn't works. Also, everything is do it from within the block. Thanks

Comment: The `_drawBlock = nil`is definitely wrong, DrawingView needs the block whenever it needs to redisplay. Without that line, you should try to find the problem as to why it makes performance slow and leaks memory.

Comment: Yes, if I do "_drawBlock = nil" lines disappear from UIView, but reference to this UIView is maintained and creates leak. I'm still investigating...